# ReactJS/ React-Router: How to filter nested array and objects based on url path parameters?

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, jsx

I have the following set up:

Navigating to StudentsBoard:

```
  <Link to={`/StudentsBoard/Kev/monday/blue`}></Link>
```

How route is set up:

```
  <Route
    component={StudentsBoard}
    path='/StudentsBoard/:name/:day/:color'
  />
```

And on the StudentsBoard page:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let student = state.students.filter(student => student.name == ownProps.params.name)

  let day = ownProps.params.day
  let color = ownProps.params.color

  return {
    carFiles: student[0].day.color //Getting an error here saying day and color are - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'day'/'color' of undefined
  }
}
```

But for `let day` and `let color` I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'day'/'color' of undefined`

How can I make the passed in params, `day` and `color` as references to the property in `student[0]`? Or is there a better way to filter an object based on parameters passed in via `ownProps.params`? Would like to ultimately get down to the color object.

Thank you and will be sure to vote up and accept answer

**EDIT**

Data structure:

```
students: [
  {
    name: Kev
    monday: {
      blue: {
        room: 5
      },
      pink: {
        root: 6
      }
    },
    tuesday: {
      green: {
        room: 7
      },
      purple: {
        root: 8
      }
    },
  },
  {
    name: Jerome
    monday: {
      black: {
        room: 5
      },
      orange: {
        root: 6
      }
    },
    tuesday: {
      yellow: {
        room: 7
      },
      purple: {
        root: 8
      }
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `student[0][day][color]`?

Comment: @jukempff Oh man how did that work? Shouldn't it be `.`? Thought `[]` references array index.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a comment, you'll need to use

```
students[0][day][color]
```

What you did, was trying to access an object which would have to look like this:

```
var students = [{
    day: {
        color: {}
    }
}]
```

Let me explain with an example:

```
student.monday
```

is the same as

```
student['monday']
```

Of course, the `.monday` version is more convenient, but when using `['monday']`, it gives you the ability to swap `'monday'` with the variable `day`, which represents a string, e.g. `'monday'`.

```
var propertyName = 'monday';
student[propertyName];
```

You should generally use the `.monday` variant, whenever possible, and only use the brackets, if you have to (like in your case).

And you should also add some sort of error handling, if a property on your data structure does not exist. Since you are dealing with strings from a URL - which a user can alter - your code may break.

```
// check if day and color properties are available
// for that student
if(!students[0][day] || !students[0][day][color]) {
    // either day or color does not exist on student
    return { carFiles: null };
}
// All good, proceed as normal
```

Please note, that your component then would need to handle the case, where `this.props.carFiles` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. So in the case of string representing an object, use the bracket? Is the bracket javascript? Lastly, do you mind showing a sample of the error handling? That's a good call.

Comment: The string is not representing an object. It is just a string, but if your data object has a property that reads the same as the string does, you can access the value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

. and [' '] is an equivalence. But I don't understand why you used 'day' and 'color' here? There are no such fields in your data structure. Can you print them out in your console.log to view the day and color at first place before your parse them out from object?